# While spoting a liar, whether observing the verbal cue or observing the non-verbal cue helps?

Tags: social-psychology, behaviorism, deception

While spotting a liar,is it paying attention to verbal cues such as
**pauses in speech and speech disturbances, including "ahs," stutters, and incomplete sentences** that weighs more or
is it paying attention to non-verbal cues such as
**inconsistent eye contact, increased degree of eye contact, blink frequency, chin movement** that weighs more

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear whether you are asking how much weight *should* we place on different cues (if we want to spot liars) or how much people actually *do* use these cues. There is a big literature on lie detection though. [Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.475.9615&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a recent paper that discusses some of this work and will give you a start.

Some of the salient points are:

- People are actually pretty bad at guessing truths and lies, though it is hard to do experiments on.
- Although there are some cues that give people away, these are faint and unreliable. The most reliable ones are actually just the things that they say (the facts).
- Non-verbal cues and speech disturbances are actually pretty poor cues even though people think they are good ones. They are also pretty easy to fake.

Comment: Also see [this paper](http://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/fulltext/S1364-6613(16)30054-7).